# Cannot bind properties to custom ItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch

I have a simple item writer looks like this:

```
public class EntityItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T>, InitializingBean {

  private String name;

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
    //writes to db
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.hasLength(name);   //assertion fails
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

and my job-definition.xml has a bean like this:

```
<bean id="EntityItemWriter" class="com.example.EntityItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="name" value="someRandomString" />
</bean>
```

When the batch job is in writing step, name property of EntityItemWriter is not set to "someRandomString" and stays as null. Is there anything that I am missing?

spring-batch version: 2.1.0.M3
spring version: 3.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Add your answer below so you can close out the question.

Comment: isn't it because you set the scope to step?

Comment: no, actually it was because I had duplicate bean `EntityItemWriter` in my xml